# Discord Bot command not functioning

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from apikeys import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

dictionary = ["aaa"]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    print("test")
    await ctx.send("Hello, I am bot")


client.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

When I run the code it says
`We have logged in as demo-python-v2#1499`
meaning that its not a connectivity issue.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the intent enabled on the developer portal as well?

Comment: Try using `intents = discord.Intents.all()` instead.

Comment: Are you on 2.0 or 1.7.3? No repro on 1.7.3 with intents set and left at default.